# graph degrees question (combinatorics)

Tags: graph-theory

let it be $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ which represents a series of positive integer numbers, so that $n\gt d1 \gt d2 \gt ... \gt d_n \ge 0$.
let it be $K\ge d_1$.

given that $(K,d_2,...,d_n,1,1...,1)$ represents a series of degrees of graph vertices', when the quantity of 1 that appears after dn is $K-d_1$,
prove that $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ also represents a series of degrees of graph vertices'.

the only thing I succeed here is showing that $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ can be a series which the sum of it degrees is even, and that is not enough.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with $v_1$, the vertex with degree $d_1$ in the original graph. How would you modify it so as to increase its degree to $K$, attach $K-d_1$ new vertices each with degree one, and leave all other original vertices untouched?